# how can I install jags on remote server?

Tags: r, sudo, jags

I need to install jags so that I can use rjags (r package) for another r package, infercnv. I was able to do this on my own computer by downloading it through home-brew, but I am unable to do so on a remote server I'm using.

I tried using this code below, but I do not have the access to run sudo on the remote server. Any advise?

```
sudo apt-get install jags
```

Comment: A couple of options come to mind.  1) Install on a similar host (cpu arch/operating system), where you have admin rights., Copy to target machine alongside your R code, set appropriate environment variables to allow R to find it.   Or 2) If you have build tools, gcc, make etc on the machine, build it from source, as far as the "make install" step, set appropriate environment variables to allow R to find it in the build folder.